# Passing variables into data.table

Tags: r, variables, filter, data.table, subset

I have a question about passing variables into a data.table to filter rows.
I am using this in a function where the name of the filter column in the data.table could change.

I understand how it would work as long as the parameter name is different than the data.table column name.
However, there is a rare chance that the name of the parameter could be the same as the data.table column name. If this happens, my code would break. Is there a way to make sure my code would never break if either scenario occurs?

```
# Example:

DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT2 = data.table(x2=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)

# This works
x <- "x2"
DT2[get(x) == "b"]
DT2[DT2[[x]] == "b"]

# This doesn't work
x <- "x"
DT[get(x) == "b"]
DT[DT[[x]] == "b"]

# I can get x="x" to work if I use eval, but then it would break if x!="x"
x <- "x"
DT[eval(x) == "b"]     # Works
x <- "x2"
DT2[eval(x) == "b"]    # Doesn't work
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `DT[.("b"), on=x, nomatch=0]`

Comment: Great. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use "eval" (not "get") in this way:

```
x <- "x"

DT[DT[,eval(x)]=="b",]
   x y v
1: b 1 1
2: b 3 2
3: b 6 3
```

It works!

```
DT2[DT2[[eval(x)]]=="b",]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: x2,y,v
```

In this second case you don't have column "x", but it works yet.

Answer (score 1):

For the case here of equality matching, a join works:

```
DT[.("b"), on=x, nomatch=0]
```